# Using class CORE_CLASS that is non API on version '2.4.6-p1'

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I have generated the **Upgrade Compatibility Tool** Report and most of the errors are as below.

> [ERROR] [1124] Line 30: Using class 'Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config' that is non API on version '2.4.6-p1'
>
> [ERROR] [1124] Line 56: Using class
> 'Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config' that is non API on version
> '2.4.6-p1'
>
> [ERROR] [1124] Line 56: Using class
> 'Magento\Framework\Filter\DataObject\Grid' that is non API on version
> '2.4.6-p1'
>
> [ERROR] [1124] Line 56: Using class
> 'Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper' that is non API on version
> '2.4.6-p1'
>
> [ERROR] [1124] Line 100: Using class
> 'Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config' that is non API on version
> '2.4.6-p1'
>
> [ERROR] [1224] Line 100: Using constant
> 'Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config::DEFAULT_ADDRESS_FORMAT' that
> is non API on version '2.4.6-p1'
>
> [ERROR] [1429] Line 100: Call method
> 'Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config::getFormatByCode' that is non
> API on version '2.4.6-p1'
>
> [ERROR] [1429] Line 100: Call method
> 'Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper::toFlatArray' that is non API
> on version '2.4.6-p1'

I'm not able to find the alternative solution for above issues, even if I use @api in DocBlock, it's not helpful.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

As per the dev document, I found this -

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/reporting/error-messages.html?lang=en

Error code - 1124   - Using non-Adobe Commerce API class The extended class is no longer present in the codebase. Update code to use a class marked as @api. Otherwise, the functionality relying on this implementation should be tested after the upgrade.

There won't be any errors as there is no class marked as @api that we can use in this case, so we need to just test the functionality.